# What does it mean "completely accountless clearing"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Source: http://szabo.best.vwh.net/bearer_contracts.html

Cite:

> With ideal two-way anonymous communications between use-once keys, and
>   **completely accountless clearing**, unlinkability via blind signatures
>   becomes redundant. This ideal case has yet to be even closely
>   approached with implemented technology, and necessarily involves long
>   communications delays which are often intolerable. Real imperfect
>   communications mixes and less expensive blinded tokens complement each
>   other.

**completely accountless clearing**

I can't understand what does it mean "acountless clearing" is it just mean "without account", what does it mean "clearing" at the end?

Comment: It means clearing digital transactions without having to tie them to a named and enduring account. Once a transaction is cleared it leaves no trace of the parties involved, exactly as when you make purchases in cash.

Comment: Could you say in another way this expression? Am I right: "communications with completely untraceble inputs"

Comment: That's the **effect**, but as mentioned at the end of the sentence, there are other means of accomplishing "untraceable inputs", so you're not saying the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, "completely accountless clearing" means clearing without an account. In this context, "[clearing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clearing_%28finance%29)" means retiring an obligation or promise by satisfying it. So if you promise to pay me $10, "clearing" that promise means that the promise is no longer outstanding because you somehow satisfied it.